# How to pass Parameters in Route Urls in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can we pass parameters to partial view in angularJs. I am new to angular ,I am following [**These**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_views.htm) tutorials for learning .This tutorial explain basic quite well but nothing about how can we send parameter to partial view.
e.g `/addStudent?id=45`

```
 $routeProvider.
                   when('/addStudent', {
                      templateUrl: 'addStudent.htm',
                      controller: 'AddStudentController'
                   }).
                   when('/viewStudents', {
                      templateUrl: 'viewStudents.htm',
                      controller: 'ViewStudentsController'
                   })
```

Answer (score 4):

You can define parameter in address definition and access it by `$stateParams` controller parameter

```
  when(url: '/new/:portfolioId',
    templateUrl: 'new.html',
    controller: function($scope, $stateParams) {
      $scope.portfolioId = $stateParams.portfolioId;
    }
  )
```

Look here: http://benfoster.io/blog/ui-router-optional-parameters

Answer (score 3):

The more "Angular way" to achieve that is by using the `$routeParams` service.

Check [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams).

Answer (score 2):

to pass parameter in route you can define parameter as `:parameter` in you url

like :

```
$routeProvider.
               when('/addStudent', {
                  templateUrl: 'addStudent.htm',
                  controller: 'AddStudentController'
               }).
               when('/viewStudents', {
                  templateUrl: 'viewStudents.htm',
                  controller: 'ViewStudentsController'
               }).
               when('/students/:id', {
                  templateUrl: 'studentsDetail.htm',
                  controller: 'studentsDetailController'
               })
```

here url `students/:id` has id as a parameter.

Here is [angular doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07)

Answer (score 2):

```
$routeProvider.when('/addStudent/:id', {
                 templateUrl: 'addStudent.htm',
                 controller: 'AddStudentController'
                   })

$routeProvider.when('/viewStudents/:id', {
                 templateUrl: 'viewStudents.htm',
                 controller: 'ViewStudentsController'
                   })
```

Comment: Explain why this is a correct answer else it will be deleted.

Comment: The URLs in the when() calls now define a parameter. It is the part starting from the colon (:param)

AngularJS will now extract from the URL (route path) whatever comes after the #/route1/ part.

Comment: Code-only answers, while they are permitted, they don't tend to get a whole lot of upvotes. Try explaining *why* the code works and what problems it addresses and how. I disagree with Mamta about it being deleted, but it's just not as useful as an answer that's well documented. Just my $0.02.